# How do I change the color of the prompt in the mini-buffer?

Tags: faces, minibuffer

I am using the zenburn theme and my mini-buffer prompt is unreadable (image attached). Please help me. I am just learning emacs.[image]

Comment: Sounds like the theme messes with face `minibuffer-prompt`. `M-x customize-face` for it.

Answer (score 9):

It's not obvious how to find out what face it is. The usual way is to put your cursor on some text and then use `C-u` `C-x` `=` but that's harder to do in the minibuffer. The other way I know of is to use `M-x` `list-faces-display` to see all the defined faces, and then you can look for something that has the same colors as the text you want to change.

In this case the face you're looking for is `minibuffer-prompt`. Try `M-x` `customize-face` `minibuffer-prompt`; you can set a foreground and background color there.

Comment: This is the answer.  BTW: `M-x customize-face RET` (or similar) followed by repeating left arrow puts cursor within the prompt. Then `C-u C-x =` shows info about the current position, including its face.